# How to ensure nfs-server is not started until it can resolve hostnames? (16.10)

Tags: networking, server, 16.10, systemd, nfs

**Summary**: Is there a way to make sure that the NFS server isn't started by systemd until it can properly resolve client machine names specified in `/etc/exports`?

**Problem description**:
I have found that NFS shares are not made properly available after the server (running 16.10) reboots. Clients get "access denied by server" errors, until `exportfs -ra` or `service nfs-server restart` is manually run on the server. After that, everything works as expected.

The server's `/etc/exports` contains only:

```
/mnt/raidarray clientmachine(rw)
```

where `clientmachine` is the hostname of the NFS client machine on the local network.

**Problem identification**: The output of `systemctl status nfs-server` (below) makes the problem clear: the name of the client can't be resolved at the time that the NFS server was started.

```
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-01-17 16:47:38 CST; 26min ago
Main PID: 1520 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service
Jan 17 16:47:38 servermachine exportfs[1511]: exportfs: Failed to resolve clientmachine
Jan 17 16:47:38 servermachine systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

`NetworkManager-wait-online.service` is enabled, which I [had understood](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) serves to make sure that `network.target` (on which `nfs-server` depends) is not satisfied until `network-online.target` is satisfied.

**Things that did not help**:

1. In case I misunderstood what `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` does, I tried adding an explicit `After=network-online.target` and `Wants=network-online.target` to `nfs-server.service`. This doesn't fix anything. I see the new dependency show up in `systemctl list-dependencies`, but name resolution still fails at boot. So it seems that `network-online.target` doesn't guarantee that hostname resolution can happen.
2. Some googling suggested that requiring `nss-lookup.target` would ensure that network resolution is available, but adding it as a `Wants` and/or `After` dependency to `nfs-server.service` doesn't fix things either!
3. Adding a  `Wants` and/or `After` dependency on `systemd-resolved.service` instead of `nss-lookup.target` doesn't fix things either.

After adding all of these dependencies, `nfs-server` starts up very very late in the boot process (just before the desktop login things), but it still can't resolve hosts. Based on `systemd-analyze plot`, it appears that `nmbd` is wedged around this time, but I don't know if that's related.

**Configuration information**: This is on a desktop version of kubuntu 16.10 that is basically a fresh install.

`NetworkManager.service` is enabled and `systemd-networkd.service` is disabled -- I didn't change that from the default.

Here is the `NetworkManager-wait-online` service definition:

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Manager Wait Online
Documentation=man:nm-online(1)
Requisite=NetworkManager.service
After=NetworkManager.service
Before=network-online.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=30
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

As a workaround I could hard-code IP addresses instead of hostnames into `/etc/exports` or `/etc/hosts`, but this seems somewhat brittle. Is there a better answer?

**EDIT - Update**: following @muru's advice below, I tried making a script to wait to resolve hostnames -- just to see how long it takes. My script has to wait tens of seconds after `systemd-resolved` starts before it can actually resolve a host. This is very bizarre. I wonder if it's actually a local networking issue? Sounds like maybe a hard-coded (and auto-updating, perhaps, as suggested by @mark-stosberg) `/etc/exports` or `/etc/hosts` file is warranted.

Comment: Hack: Create a script which waits for successful DNS resolution, then use that as an `ExecStartPre` for the `nfs-server` service

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you do a `systemd-analyze plot > /tmp/systemd.svg`, post a link to `systemd.svg` and post the contents of `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/NetworkManager-wait-online.service` as well?  then drop me a note @fabby

Comment: Hrmpf! What you already did was what I was going to propose...  BTW, you should [edit] your question and provide the above critical info there so the next user looking at your question doesn't have to dig through the entire comment section.

Comment: @muru IMNSHO, your suggestion is the best one.  Could you provide an answer for that???  If you ping me, I'll come back and upvote!  ;-)

Comment: Why hard-code and auto-update `/etc/hosts` instead of `/etc/exports` itself?

Comment: If `/etc/exports` is hard-coded, it will just contain the raw IP addresses -- so you need a template file (or special comment lines) to store the hostname to look up. That's a reasonable solution. Alternately, if `/etc/hosts` is used, that stores the hostname and IP both, and then the automatic updater would just need to revise the hostname to IP mapping. Both seem like reasonable approaches that might be useful in different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @muru's comment, I made a python script to wait until DNS resolution:

```
import socket
import time
import itertools

TIMEOUT = 30
HOSTS = ['stanford.edu', 'google.com', 'example.com']

def main():
    hosts = itertools.cycle(HOSTS)
    t0 = time.time()
    for host in hosts:
        t = time.time()
        elapsed = t - t0
        if elapsed > TIMEOUT:
            break
        try:
            socket.getaddrinfo(host, None, proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
            print('Resolved {} at t = {}'.format(host, elapsed))
            break
        except socket.gaierror:
            print('Could not resolve {} at t = {}'.format(host, elapsed))
        time.sleep(0.25)
        t = time.time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I saved that script as `/etc/systemd/system/nfs-server.service.d/wait_for_dns.py` (one has to make the parent directory first), and then ran `sudo systemctl edit --full nfs-server`, adding the following before other ExecStartPre lines:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python3 /etc/systemd/system/nfs-server.service.d/wait_for_dns.py
```

This worked fine, though it certainly feels a bit hackish and could be improved in many ways. (I eventually just gave up on NFS in this context; it was more of a pain than it was worth.)

Comment: I had this same issue in Ubuntu 20.04 and nothing else worked but this fixed it! Such a hack. For me the delay was about 3 seconds before DNS resolution was successful.

Comment: There's a simpler one-liner version of this here: https://serverfault.com/a/867845/406162

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what you are trying to do with `systemd`, you've already tried to do the best thing, which is to set your service to start after `network-online`. I read a lot of a `systemd` questions, and others have reported problems with the network not being fully online when they do this.

I recommend the idea of putting IP addresses in `/etc/exports` or `/etc/hosts` as you recommend. This simplifies an important disk mounting task during boot-up.

To make the system more robust, you could use a cron job or systemd timer that checks periodically to see if the DNS for the interesting hosts have changed. If so, automatically update `/etc/hosts` with the new values.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure which seems like a more robust / less kludgey solution: the suggestion from @muru to make a script that waits for successful name resolution as an `ExecStartPre` component of `nfs-server.service`, or make a cron script to edit `/etc/hosts` with the latest DNS information for hosts of interest. Thoughts anyone?

Comment: If you wait for successful name resolution in `ExecStartPre`, it's possibly it will take *very* long or maybe never happen. If you update `/etc/hosts` with valid DNS entries only when valid DNS queries can be completed, the file will be maximally up to date.

Comment: Copy-paste of comments as an answer. -1

Comment: @Fabby I'm not sure what you are referring to- I didn't copy/paste anything.

Comment: A "virtual" copy-paste.  You read through the comments and reworded them as an answer without adding anything of value is what I meant... **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: @Fabby, No, I did not. And if someone had a great answer, they should have left it as an answer, not a comment!

Comment: @Fabby This answer was useful to me, at least, so it couldn't have been a total copy-paste of what I said. (And nobody other than I said anything about `/etc/hosts`...)The idea of automatically updating `/etc/hosts` was a good one, too, and hadn't occurred to me. Plus the context of this being a common systemd bugaboo is useful.

Comment: If the post is edited I can upvote instead of downvote... Leave one more comment after edit

Comment: I've (trivially) editted the post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS installation.
The exportfs did not run properly after a reboot and thus the nfs-kernel-server did not start properly.
I tried to add a sleep to the start case in /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server but that did not help.
I also tried some hints found https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/nfs-kernel-server-wont-start-on-boot/5936/7
I finally solved the problem by adding the following line to /etc/rc.local

```
systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

Answer (score 0):

this was bugging me for weeks. At first I didn't figure it out why does KODI on my TV suddenly don't see NFS shares. And then I couldn't figure it out how to solve that because all solutions I found didn't work on 19.04.

But adding a cron job with

```
systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

as command after every reboot solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today (I am on AlmaLinux 8.6), and fixed with
systemctl edit nfs-server:

```
[Unit]  
Requires=network.target network-online.target  
After=network.target network-online.target
```